# How do you render a list of classes inside another class in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, class, components

I have a class called Transactions and a class called Students.
When I render Students I would like to also render a list of Transactions.

For example, something like this:

```
<Student name="John" transactions="
                                   <transactions item='Bread' amount='1'/>
                                   <transactions item='Butter' amount='2'/>
                                   <transactions item='Milk' amount='3'/>
                                   <transactions item='Egg' amount='4'/>"
/>
```

Is this possible in React?

**EDIT:** What if I have multiple students with different transactions? How do I render each list of transactions into each student?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that `Student` is supposed to render a list of `Transactions`, it likely should accept not a list of components but a list of transactions, e.g.:

```
class Student extends Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.transactions.map(({ item, amount }) =>
    <Transactions item={ item } amount={ amount } />
    ); 
  }
}
```

And be used like:

```
<Student transactions={[
  { item: 'foo', amount: 1 },
  { item: 'bar', amount: 2 }
]} />
```

Depending on how transactions are structured, they could be stored in more convenient way like `Map`.

Comment: After trying this, it says `this.props.transactions.map is not a function`.
Do you know what causes this?

Comment: This means that `transactions` prop wasn't provided with an array.

Comment: I'm guessing this is because `transactions` happens to be empty. I'll try fixing that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple.
You have to use `render(){}` in your `<Student />` class. Look at the sample code below.

```
class Student extends React.Component {
  render(){
    <transactions item='Bread' amount='1'/>
    <transactions item='Butter' amount='2'/>
    <transactions item='Milk' amount='3'/>
    <transactions item='Egg' amount='4'/>
  }
}
```

It's called **nested components** for more search. I hope my answer be useful for you.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified my question more. What if I have multiple students with different transactions?